# How to install flutter and dart in Xcode macosx?

Tags: xcode, flutter, ide, mobile-development

I need to know if there is any way or plugin to run dart code on Xcode for flutter app development. If there is any mention here, every time I searched on internet it only shows me flutter commands for terminal to run app on iOS. I want my IDE to be XCODE for flutter development. here is what flutter official documentations says when I ask same question
[Flutter Documentation about MacOS](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such plugin for XCode.

Comment: You are sure about it, i thought so also but if they have for Android Studio, they might have one for Xcode too.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Dart officially supported IntelliJ/Webstorm for many years and Android Studio is pretty much the same. VSCode is a community project that Google supports. There haven't been any XCode efforts been mentioned so far.

Comment: Okay Thank you so much. :)

Comment: VSCode plugin isn't exactly a "community" project.  Danny is on contract to Google, so he's a lot more of an insider.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can install and use flutter on macOS. But you can not use XCode as IDE, officially they announced either use **Android Studio / IntelliJ** or **Visual Studio Code.**

For Android Studio / IntelliJ:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio

For Visual Studio Code:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode

As a suggestion iOS or other developer should use VSCode its light weighted and more understandable and android developer have their own option.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Dart and Flutter are officially supported by IntelliJ/Android Studio and VSCode.

I think there is some integration with VIM and Emacs, but not officially supported. There is no integration with XCode though.